# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, collections, classcastexception

```
Iterator<Object> itr=list.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
Object []obj=(Object[]) itr.next();------------------//line1
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
                jo.put("routeNo", (int)obj[6]);
                jo.put("routeName", obj[5].toString());
                jo.put("stopSequenceID", (int)obj[4]);
                jo.put("stopID", (int)obj[3]);
                jo.put("stopName",obj[2].toString());
                jo.put("lat", (double)obj[1]);
                jo.put("lon", (double)obj[0]);
}
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;---------------------at line(1)
```

I am converting list to Object[].

As 'list' object contains 750 records.
with the fields I am putting it on the 'jo' object. Each record contains those 7 fields.

Please help me .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't be done.  An `Object` is not an `Object[]`.  Perhaps if you explained *what* you needed to do with it, then we'd be able to help you out a bit better?  Also, why you've got a collection of `Objects` in the first place is a bit bizarre...could you elaborate as to what that collection should contain?

Comment: There is a `Double` in your list, that's all.

Comment: you're trying to cast a double to an array of objects, exactly as the error message says.

Comment: why casting object (which is a Double) to an array of object?

Comment: my requirement is while list is iterated those index positions should be set for that key value.

Answer (score 1):

[`itr.next();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) Returns an `Object` in your case. Why are you casting it to `Object []`?

You probably meant to do something like that:

```
Iterator<Double> itr=list.iterator();
ArrayList<Double> items = new ArrayList<>();
   while(itr.hasNext()) {
       items.add(itr.next());
   }
```

Note that defining `JSONObject jo` shouldn't be inside your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `List<Double>` to `Object[]` using `toArray`

```
  List<Double> list=new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(10.0);
  list.add(10.0);
  list.add(10.0);

 Object[] obj=list.toArray();
```